# Fetching a specific record from a column which has comma delimited values

Tags: oracle

This is my first post and I hope to receive an answer. I am stuck with an awkward situation where I am required to fetch a specific record value from a column (this column has multiple data delimited by a comma.

Example: I would like to fetch BuyProtection, in col inputs from table abc.
Column inputs has following data:

```
{CLIENT_EMAIL=, CreditDefaultSwap=CDS, REF_ASSET_SENIORITY=SEN, IS_DNA=true, BUY_SELL=**BuyProtection**, ROW=123}
```

How do I fetch this record?

Thanks,
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a great opportunity to use the like operator.

```
SELECT inputs FROM abc WHERE inputs LIKE '%BuyProtection%'
```

In words, the result set returns all records where BuyProtection is somewhere in the column inputs.  The character, `%`, is a wildcard which can be placed anywhere in the matching term, `'%BuyProtection%'`, and it is associated with o or more characters.